# C++ map not inserting properly

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap, std

I am trying to populate a map from the following structs:

```
struct CounterParty
{
    uint8_t firm_id;
    char trader_tag[3];
    uint32_t qty;
};
struct OrderFillMessage
{
    Header header;
    uint32_t order_id;
    uint64_t fill_price;
    uint32_t fill_qty;
    uint8_t no_of_contras;
    std::vector<CounterParty> CounterPartyGroup;
    char termination_string[8]; 
};

void TradeDecoder::findMostActiveTrader()
{
    map<char*,int> traders_volume_map;
    for(OrderFillMessage m: OrderFillMessages)
    {
        for(CounterParty cp: m.CounterPartyGroup)
        {
            outputfile<<cp.trader_tag<<" "<<cp.qty<<endl;
            traders_volume_map[cp.trader_tag]+=cp.qty;
        }
    }
    outputFileTrader<<"PRINTING MAP "<<traders_volume_map.size()<<"\n";
    for(auto it=traders_volume_map.begin(); it!=traders_volume_map.end(); it++)
    {
        outputFileTrader<<(it)->first<<(it)->second<<endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, its just a simple insert or update map function.

```
outputfile<<cp.trader_tag<<" "<<cp.qty<<endl;
```

prints the following:

```
IYH 2
HTC 1
IYH 2
HTC 1
IYH 2
HTC 1
IYH 1
HTC 1
IYH 1
HTC 1
IYH 1
HTC 1
IYH 1
HTC 1
IYH 1
```

however `outputFileTrader<<"PRINTING MAP "<<traders_volume_map.size()<<"\n";` prints:

```
PRINTING MAP 1
HTC3050
```

Which means that nothing was added to the map, and everything was found even though there is only 1 element in map!?

Any insights as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!!

Though I do not think this would cause the map lookup issue, I want to add that `trader_tag` is a not null terminated `char[3]`.

Comment: Why is your naming convention inconsistent? i.e. Should `CounterPartyGroup` be counter_party_group`. Also using plurals is a not a good idea when you are also using the singular

Comment: `cp.trader_tag` probably has the same value every loop iteration.  You are using *the address of a local variable* as your map key.  (causing undefined behaviour). To avoid this behaviour, use `std::string` as the key.

Comment: cp.trader_tag doesnt have the same value, I showed it in the post.

Comment: You did not print the pointer but the value pointer _trader_tag_ points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `char *` for the key. This is a bad idea as this will vary considerably.

Use the following

```
map<std::string, int> traders_volume_map;
```

to overcome this problem.

Comment: I cant change to string because: trader_tag is char[3], and its not null terminated... If I were to null terminate it, I need to do char[2]='\0', which would overwrite the last character in trader_tag

Comment: @weizeng You can change to a `std::string`:  `std::string x(trader_tag, 3);`  Please look at the documentation on how to construct a string [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) and look at constructor `4)`.

Comment: You are lucky with `outputfile<<cp.trader_tag<<" "<<cp.qty<<endl;`

Comment: I think I've thought of a work around though... I'll just add another field in my structure, something like char trader_tag_string[4], and add null character there...

Comment: @weizeng The workaround is to read the documentation on `std::string` carefully and not just assume you can't create a `std::string` from a non-null terminated array of char.

Comment: Paul you are genius. Ty!

Comment: @weizeng `traders_volume_map[std::string(cp.trader_tag,3)] += cp.qty;` -- This is what the answer is suggesting that you do.